# Truncate string and add word after the nth word

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string which has values like "Zesty Bean Bites South of the Border".

I would like to cut it down to three words and append an ellipsis, yielding "Zesty Bean Bites..."

I tried using the substring() method but it won't split on words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This handles if there are fewer than three strings.

I'd also consider doing it by character counts:

```
public string NewTitle(string OldTitle)
    {
        int HowManyWords = 3;
        string RetValue = "";
        string[] parts = OldTitle.Split(' ');
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                RetValue += parts[i];
            }
            else
            {
                RetValue += " " + parts[i];
            }
            if (i >= (HowManyWords-1))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return RetValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx) method and use the 'space' character as the delimiter. Then use the [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method to join them together.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
string title = "Zesty Bean Bites South of the Border";
string[] aParts = title.split(' ');
string newTitle = aParts[0] + aParts[1] + aParts[2] + "...";
```

If you need the rest of the string after the ellipsis, continue with:

```
newTitle += aParts[3] + aParts[4] + aParts[5] + aParts[6];
```

Of course, if the title length varies, this would be more appropriate in a loop, and adding the ellipsis after aParts[2].  To be safe, check aParts.Length to make sure that you actually HAVE three words to put the ellipsis after.

Comment: what if aParts[2] is null . We have to check this also

Comment: Agreed.  What if aParts[2] IS null?  What would you like to do?  You mentioned that you wanted to add "..." after the 3rd word in the title.  Do you still want to add it if there aren't 3 words in the title?  Do you want to just forget it, since the title isn't long enough?  YOU tell ME what you'd like to do.

Comment: u can check with ?? operator if it is null.